# Biztalk got an error "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server"

Tags: biztalk

Our Biztalk (2006R2) faced an error as below:

**Error 1**
Event Type:        Error
Event Source:    ENTSSO
Event Category:                Enterprise Single Sign-On 
Event ID:              10514
Date:                     2/14/2014
Time:                     5:02:27 PM
User:                     N/A
Computer:          NINI-SSPP03
Description:
An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.
Function: GetGlobalInfo
File: infocache.cpp:1349
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.).
SQL Error code: 0x00000040
Error code: 0xC0002A21, An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.

**Error2**
The following stored procedure call failed: " { call admsvr_ReceiveLocation_GetAllInApp( ?)}". SQL Server returned error string: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.".

But we cannot find any error in SQL Server event log and SQL Server log.

Is there any idea on the possible cause of this error?

Thanks.

Comment: With the SSO database, have you changed user credentials (changed a password)?  Or, more obviously, is the SSO service running?

Comment: Not only on SSO database, but also in other Biztalk database. But the strange point is: we cannot find any errors in the Biztalk SQL server.

Comment: Is this fatal or intermittent?

Comment: @DavidHoerster, it is intermittent, after a while the service is resumed normal. In fact we just discover that problem when sample checking the event log in Biztalk server.

Comment: is your BizTalk server a Virtual Machine?  If so read this blog here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prethishkumar/archive/2012/02/04/high-performing-biztalk-server-2009-biztalk-server-2010-server-setup.aspx

Comment: It is physical server, not virtual server.

Comment: Well I would guess it's either someone or something shutting down your database or it's a network error. Check your logs on SQL Server to make sure your DB was running. If it was then check for faulty NICs or switches.